# Using references of a referenced project

Tags: c#

I am trying to split up my solution into a main project and a project containing some helper classes. The "helper project" uses some external libraries, like e.g. NLog.

I reference NLog in my csproj file like this:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="NLog" Version="4.6.6" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I can use NLog in my helper project fine. But the helper project will probably be used in many different main projects, so it would be nice if just referencing the helper project from my main project would also give me access to NLog in my main project, but that does not work. I always have to explicitly add a  reference to NLog in my main project.

Is there anything I can do to reference NLog in my main project without manually adding the reference to NLog there?

Comment: Actually, I'd recommend _not_ to reference NLog in your helper project, but only use a logging facade/interface. What if you need to use it in a project, where some different logging framework is used? What I am saying is: Your main project should determine the logging frame work, not the helper.

Comment: @Fildor makes a really good point, but if you're at the point of understanding references themself, it might be a stretch too far for right now ;)

Comment: What kind of project are you using - "SDK style" (the new style introduced for .NET Core) or the old style? In the SDK style projects, references should work transitively.

Comment: It is a VFAQ.  Google ".net core copy dependencies".

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Unfortunately i have to stick to .NET Framework and cannot use .NET Core.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there anything I can do to reference NLog in my main project without manually adding the reference to NLog there?

No, that's the way references work. You need to add the package reference to every project that uses it directly *.

---

However, the way logging is usually handled is that the "helper" library does not know anything whatsoever about the *actual* library used for logging. It simply knows about an interface. A *overly simplified* example is:

```
public interface ILogger
{
    void Log(string message);
}
```

And then it is the job of the hosting application to have an implementation of that interface (say, using NLog) and pass it to the helper classes using dependency injection.

---

<sub>* There is a case where you don't need a reference, but its somewhat esoteric. If your assembly doesn't directly use a reference, but merely sits in the middle between two assemblies which do. You do not need to add the reference directly. It is not relevant in your specific case</sub>

Comment: "You need to add the package reference to every project that uses it." Not in an SDK style project. References are transitive.

Comment: @JonSkeet so what you're saying is that if my assembly is in the middle between something that hosts and something downstream which uses a reference my "in the middle" assembly doesn't directly need the reference? Have I understood you correctly.

Comment: Yes. For example, Google.Cloud.Firestore.V1 depends on Google.Api.Gax.Grpc, which depends on Google.Api.CommonProtos, which depends on Google.Protobuf. If your project depends on Google.Cloud.Firestore.V1, you can use types from Google.Protobuf without adding any other references.